# how to retrieve-albums-images-from-facebook-using-graph-api-ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting json format   correctly but the thing is i want to retrieve album images one by one and display it in grid view ...please anybody suggest some code or idea... 
Pl suggest me how to get album id for each photos in albums

```
  Results: {
         data =     (
        {
    "can_upload" = 1;
    count = 2;
    "cover_photo" = 1404379296458611;
    "created_time" = "2013-10-04T11:35:21+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1404366983126509;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1404366983126509&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741827";
    name = "Photos";
    privacy = custom;
    type = app;
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-09T07:41:48+0000";
},
        {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    "created_time" = "2013-10-08T10:55:52+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1406014439628430;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1406014439628430&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741829";
    name = "he Photos";
    privacy = custom;
    type = app;
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-08T11:33:49+0000";
},
        {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    count = 1;
    "cover_photo" = 1405547679675106;
    "created_time" = "2013-10-07T06:21:36+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1405547666341774;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1405547666341774&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741828";
    name = test;
    privacy = everyone;
    type = normal;
    "updated_time" = "2013-10-07T06:21:47+0000";
},
        {
    "can_upload" = 0;
    "created_time" = "2013-09-25T05:30:31+0000";
    from =             {
        id = 100006596624401;
        name = "sample";
    };
    id = 1399900213573186;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=1399900213573186&id=100006596624401&aid=1073741825";
    name = "iOS Photos";
    privacy = everyone;
    type = app;
    "updated_time" = "2013-09-25T06:26:13+0000";
}
);
paging =     {
    cursors =         {
     after = "MTM5OTkwMDIxMzU3MzE4Ng==";
    before = "MTQwNDM2Njk4MzEyNjUwOQ==";
};
  };
```

Comment: How can you get this album id ? Is it compulsory to app get reviewed by facebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphGet:@"me/albums" withGetVars:nil];
    NSDictionary *albums = (NSDictionary *)[fb_graph_response.htmlResponse JSONValue];
    NSMutableArray * albumids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    albumids = [albums objectForKey:@"data"];

    for(int i =0; i< [albumids count]; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictuser = (NSDictionary *)[albumids objectAtIndex:i];
        [album addObject:[dictuser objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [albumname addObject:[dictuser objectForKey:@"name"]];
    }
```

Comment: fbgraphresponse which framework can u pl tell me i am using facebooksdk framework

Comment: i couldnt use fbgraph dographget

Comment: how to display all the images inside collectionview

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0 Version

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me/albums", parameters: ["fields": "photo_count,name,id" ], httpMethod: "GET")
    request?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in

    })
```

In case you want to get picture of Album then use this

**"fields": "photo_count,name,id, picture"**

Facebook also have a [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Falbums%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cphoto_count%2Cid%2Cpicture&version=v2.12) which is very helpful